# Numpy exact value

Tags: python, numpy, numeric

How do I get the initial value when a square rooted value is squared again in python?

For example :

`np.square((np.sqrt(2)))`

but the terminal gives the **'2.0000000000000004'**.

My opinion is about to square the value first, but can any correction be made in this code representation?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> round(np.square((np.sqrt(2))), 2)
2.0
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Could you give a bit of explanation? It would help OP and future readers :)